# How to unsubscribe an event-emitter

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-composition-api

for the below posted code,  i want to implement the function `unregisterEvtEmitter` so that when it is called the event emitter `evtRunWSRouteTest` is unregistered.
my attempts to achieve that is as follows:

```
function unregisterEvtEmitter() {
  evtEmitterParamsCompProperties.value = undefined
}
```

is it correct?
please let me know how to unregister an event emitter properly

**objective**

i would like to convert the below posted code into a class `GISWSCaller` and export it, so that the `evtEmitterParamsCompProperties` and `unregisterEvtEmitter` can be used from within the .vue file that in which this class will be instantiated.

i want to know how call `evtEmitterParamsCompProperties` and `unregisterEvtEmitter` on the object instatiated from that class

**code**:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <button @click="originDestLonLat('30.976639,30.056021,30.97775,30.033333')">routTest</button>
    result:{{ res }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineEmits, ref,computed,onMounted } from 'vue';
export default {
  name: 'GISWSCaller',
}
const res = ref(null)
let params = null
</script>

<script setup>
const emit = defineEmits({
  evtRunWSRouteTest:async (params) => {
    const splitted = params.split(',')
    if (splitted.length == 4) {
      const response = await fetch('https://xx/xx/getDistanceFromOriginToDestination/' + params)
      res.value =  await response.json()
      return res.value
    }
    return false
  }
})

let evtEmitterParamsCompProperties = computed({
  get() {
    return params
  },
  set(newValue) {
    emit('evtRunWSRouteTest',newValue)
  }
})

// functions
function originDestLonLat(param) {
    console.log("params:",param);
    params = param
    // emit('evtRunWSRouteTest',params)
    evtEmitterParamsCompProperties.value = param
}

function unregisterEvtEmitter() {
  evtEmitterParamsCompProperties.value = undefined
}

</script>
```

Comment: It looks unnecessarily complex. You can just use if branch if you want to conditionally emit inside a listener. It's unclear what's the point of evtRunWSRouteTest implementation here. Are you trying to use emit as comp method instead of emitting an event to a parent? This may be XY problem, consider explaining the actual problem you're trying to solve in this comp

Comment: @EstusFlask would you please tell me why it is complex?can you please provide  a non-complex version of the code

Comment: Can you comment on the rest of the previous comment? It's unclear what you're trying to achieve here in the end

Comment: I believe you are confusing 2 different things - event emitters can not be registered or unregistered. They simply emit, whenever they want to emit. You can only subscribe for or unsubscribe from a particular event which is emitted by the emitter. For Vue3 you can use [mitt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mitt) as event bus where you can emit events, subscribe for events, and unsubscribe from events.

Comment: @IVOGELOV i modified the title of the question

Comment: @EstusFlask i could not get what you mean actually..would you please clarify?

Comment: Please, explain what you try to achieve in this component instead of focusing on potentially wrong solution (unregistering a listener). How is this component used? Why is there a listener at all? Currently it looks like you're trying to use emit inside the same component, which is not how events work in V3.

Comment: @EstusFlask i added -objective- section to the question above...please have a look..is it clearer now?

Comment: Sorry, not enough. It's not shown how this comp is used and where unregisterEvtEmitter is called. It's unclear why you're using events here at all. Generally it would be written in composition as `let isUpdateStopped = false; async function evtRunWSRouteTest (params) {...}; async originDestLonLat(param) { if (isUpdateStopped) return; await evtRunWSRouteTest(...) }; function stopUpdate() { isUpdateStopped = true }`. That's all. No events.